chart.js Ticks callback not working in lwc
I have a simple bar grapgh and i need to format the Y axis labels. the code i found on Chartjs documentation is not working in LWC. not sure whats wrong with my code. currently thy axis labels are like 20,30 i want like '$20'
dataaa = {
    labels: ['janury','janury','janury','janury','janury','janury','janury','janury'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First Dataset',
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
        'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
        'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
        'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  };
 renderedCallback() {
    if(this.chartjsInitialized) {
        return;
    }
    this.chartjsInitialized = true;
  
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this,chartjs)
            ]).then(() =>{
                const ctx = this.template.querySelector('canvas.barChart').getContext('2d');
                this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: this.dataaa,
                    options: {
                      scales: {
                        y: [{
                           
                           ticks: {
                            // For a category axis, the val is the index so the lookup via getLabelForValue is needed
                            callback: function(val, index,ticks ) {
                              // Hide every 2nd tick label
                            
                              return '$ '+val;
                            }
                            
                        }
                      }]
                    },
                  }}
            );
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title : 'Error loading ChartJS',
                        message : error.message,
                        variant : 'error',
                }),
            );
        });

 
    

}


